# How prove exists a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_{n}<\infty,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}b_{n}|=\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b^2_{n}$ of postive numbers diverges. Prove that
 there exists a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ of real numbers such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_{n}<\infty
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}b_{n}|=\infty.
$$

My try: maybe this Cauchy-Schwarz inequality have usefull
$$\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^2_{n}\Big)\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b^2_{n}\Big)\ge
\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n}\Big)^2$$

Comment: Already asked several times on the site.

Answer (score 6):

Define
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2
$$
and
$$
a_n=\frac{b_n}{\sqrt{s_ns_{n-1}}}
$$
Without loss of generality, assume $b_1\ne0$.

---

Since $u-1\ge\log(u)$ for $u\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n a_kb_k
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{s_k-s_{k-1}}{\sqrt{s_ks_{k-1}}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\sqrt{\frac{s_k}{s_{k-1}}}-\sqrt{\frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k}}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=2}^n\sqrt{\frac{s_k}{s_{k-1}}}-1\\
&\ge\frac12\sum_{k=2}^n\log\left(\frac{s_k}{s_{k-1}}\right)\\[8pt]
&=\frac12(\log(s_n)-\log(s_1))
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kb_k=\infty
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n a_k^2
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{s_k-s_{k-1}}{s_ks_{k-1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{s_{k-1}}-\frac1{s_k}\\
&=\frac1{s_1}-\frac1{s_n}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k^2=\frac1{b_1^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_N= \sum_{n=1}^N b_n^2$ and take $a_n=b_n/\sqrt{S_N}$.  Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2 = 1$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n = \sqrt{S_N}$$.

Let $N\to\infty$.

Comment: How does this lead to the sequence $a_n$? If we take the limit as $N\to\infty$, we get $a_n=0$.

Comment: The question was to establish its existence, not necessarily what it looked like.

Comment: What sequence has its existence established here? All of these sequences are tending to the sequence $a_n=0$.

Comment: Put another way: For every finite $N$, your infinite sequence $(a_n)$ yields $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 = \infty$, violating the required condition.